# Linking error with swift app calling to a objc static lib

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I have an objective c static lib and need to write a swift app using the lib. The swift project compiles fine but it is reporting a linking error when I try to run.
This is how connect the objective c and swift.

1. Drag and drop the include directory with public headers to supporting files
   [image: figure 1]
2. Then added the .a lib file in to the build phases
   [image: figure 2]
3. Then created the bridging header and included the public headers of the lib there
   [image: figure 3]

This is the linker error I am getting
[image]

But the lib is built for armv7 according to lipo -info 
[image]
What am I missing here? Is this a xcode bug(I am using xcode 6.4)?

Answer (score 0):

Swift doesn't support static library.

See if updated version of your library available with swift support, That is the only work around..

Comment: No I think you can add static libs. This is a tutorial showing how to do that. https://medium.com/swift-programming/merge-objective-c-static-library-into-swift-using-mosquitto-87ce0b6ec513